# VBA: Word 2010 - Close Header & Footer Tools with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using a macro, which inserts a text into the footer. After the macro has finished, the Header & Footer Tools are active, so I'm in the editing mode for the footer. Does anyone know how to close this editmode with VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In Word 2007

```
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

I don't have W 2010 at hand to test. If it doesn't work, please post a comment and I'll delete the answer.

HTH